# Getting item in an array with matching id mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a db with some objects that have embedded array of cards.

I want to get a card with matching id from a user that matches the Id that I am looking for. so far I am only able to return the wrong card.

```
async getCard(id: string, cardId: string) {
        if (!id) throw new CardNotFoundError(id);
        let query = {'user.id': id, 'cards.id': cardId};

        const card = (await this.byQuery(query)).cards[0];
        if (card) return card;
        throw new CardNotFoundError("" || id);
    }
```

my schema

```
const CardUserSchema = new Schema(
    {
        id: {
            ...trimmedString,
            required: true,
            index: true,
            unique: true
        },
        phoneNumber: { ...trimmedString, required: true, unique: true },
        email: { ...trimmedString, required: false },
    }
const CardSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        ...trimmedString,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true
    },
})
const CardMainSchema = SchemaFactory(
    {
        id: {
            ...trimmedString,
            required: true,
            index: true,
            unique: true
        }
        user: { type: CardUserSchema, required: true },
        cards: {type: [CardSchema], default: []}
        
    })
```

Comment: please share what's the problem you are facing and some sample data for checking.

Comment: I added my question up top. I am getting the wrong card despite specifying the card id that I want.